# Move mongodb data without losing destination data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two mongodb databases.

**Development DB**

```
{
 _id:"someid",
 "parent1":{
    "key1":"val1",
    "key2":"val2",
    "key3":"val3",
    "key4":"val4",
    "key5":"val5",
    "key6":"val6"
  }
}
```

**Production DB**

```
{
 _id:"someid",
 "parent1":{
    "key1":"val1",
    "key2":"val2",
    "key3":"val3",
    "key10":"val10",
    "key11":"val11",
    "key12":"val12"
  }
}
```

I want to move my Development data to production data without losing newly added keys in production.

The output should become:

```
{
 _id:"someid",
 "parent1":{
    "key1":"val1",
    "key2":"val2",
    "key3":"val3",
    "key4":"val4",
    "key5":"val5",
    "key6":"val6"
    "key10":"val10",
    "key11":"val11",
    "key12":"val12"
  }
}
```

I can't update by using `db.collection.update(  { _id:...} , { $set: { some_key.param2 : new_info  } }`, as I can't add parent to each and every key.

Comment: what do you mean by you "can't add parent to each and every key"

Comment: @ThrowsException, there are so many keys in dev and manually adding parent is very lengthy task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your eventual needs there are a couple of approaches you can take to this:

- **Cycle Object keys and apply updates**: Being where you essentially "read" the current object and then take note of it's current state when applying individual updates per each key. Bulk operations help somewhat here:

  ```js
  var bulk = db.target.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
      count = 0;

  db.source.find().forEach(function(doc) {
      Object.keys(doc.parent1).forEach(function(key) {
          var query = { "_id": doc.id };
          query["parent1." + key] = { "$ne": doc.parent1[key] };
          var update = { "$set": {} };
          update.$set["parent1." + key] = doc.parent1[key];
          bulk.find(query).updateOne(update);
          query = { "_id": doc._id };
          update = { "$setOnInsert": {} };
          update.$setOnInsert["parent1." + key] = doc.parent1[key];
          bulk.find(query).upsert().updateOne(update);
          count++;

          if ( count % 500 == 0 ) {
              bulk.execute();
              bulk = db.target.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
          }
      });
  });

  if ( count % 500 != 0 ) 
      bulk.execute();
  ```
- **Use a utility to "merge" the results per key**: Such as with ["lodash"](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) library as in:

  ```js
  db.source.find().forEach(function(doc) {
      var id = doc._id;
      delete doc._id;

      var result = db.target.findAndModify({
          "query": { "_id": id },
          "update": { "$setOnInsert": doc },
          "upsert": true,
          "new": true
      });

      var merged = _.merge(result,doc);
      db.target.update({ "_id": merged._id }, merged );
  });
  ```

The "latter" is generally heavier in "update" and communication load though a bit lighter in overall code. You can also "tweak" this in API code where you can in fact return if the "upsert" in fact resulted in such a thing or whether the document was actually just "found", in which case a decision can be made whether to do the "merge" or not.

Of course I am "abstracting" here, as in reality you source from different "databases" and "connections" rather than just collections as is given as an example. But these are the basic model patterns to follow.